# Display issue with oh-my-zsh agnoster theme

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've added the theme in the zshrc file like so:

```
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
```

But it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. What am I missing?

Comment: Follow this: https://gist.github.com/renshuki/3cf3de6e7f00fa7e744a

Comment: This video solved my problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxDLXr8S2Yk

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As stated on the [agnoster-github-page](https://github.com/agnoster/agnoster-zsh-theme) you need either a

- Powerline-patched font
- Font that contains the characters needed

Your currently used font seems to be missing the `\ue0b0` char. It looks different from what it should look like (A full-line-height one-char-wide right pointing triangle)

I would look into some of these fonts:

- [Patched fonts for Powerline users](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)
- Being a fan of **not** using patched fonts I prefer [Hack](http://sourcefoundry.org/hack/) and [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode)

Answer (score 29):

You just need to install a font that contains these characters. for example, you can install [Powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline
```

That worked for me as well.

Comment: Additionally I had to open a terminal, go to `preferences` -> `<my active profile>` -> `Text` -> `Custom font:` and pick a font with the suffix `...for Powerline` e.g. `DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline`

Comment: what can I do if its just a wsl 2 terminal that I have with zsh? how to config it in .zshrc for example?

Answer (score 1):

Install Melno For Powerline font and Change default terminal font.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline.git

$ cd Menlo-for-Powerline

$ sudo mv Menlo* /usr/share/fonts
```

Now open terminal

```
Edit->Preferences-> Unnamed-> Text -> Check Custom font
```

- Now Select your Custom font as Melno For Powerline Regular

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on Debian 9 with urxvt.
Fixed it changing font to Hack. Thanks to @AnimiVulpis answer.

Install Hack font on Debian:

```
apt-get install fonts-hack-ttf
```

Configure on ~/.Xresources:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Hack:size=8
```

Comment: I'm on Linuxmint, and it doesn't fix it for me, same problem.